# PHP access data from embed div

Tags: php, dom

I'm not work with php, but i need to do only one task in legacy project.

I need show an external site, wait for user input data, solve captcha em click Ok. Then i need get all data loaded and save to local php vars.
In very very simple way i can show the site, btw, i don't know how i can access the generated DOM after user has send the data.
Anyone can show me the way?

```
<div id="escola" class="row">
        <embed id="preview" name="preview" type="text/html" width="1024" height="400" src=https://dfe-portal.svrs.rs.gov.br/Dfe/ConsultaPublicaDfe?chaveAcessoDfe=>
</div>
```

When the user has filled the "Chave de Acesso", then solve captcha and click "Consultar" i want get every fields and save to my database, but, how i can access the fields?

For example, use 43230302247794000118650040002994621366786710 for "Chave de acesso"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not possible with pure PHP. PHP has no relation to what happens in the browser.

Comment: When sites are using a CAPTCHA, you can usually assume that they do not _want_ you to access their data in such an automated way to begin with. PHP won't help you here, because the embed is a client-side construct, that PHP doesn't know about. And client-side JavaScript won't get you access to the content of the embed element, keyword Same Origin Policy. You should contact the provider of this service, and ask them whether they are providing any API for the kind of access you want.